# Updating Tkinter Canvas with Subprocess PIPE Output, Threads required?

Tags: python, multithreading, canvas, tkinter, subprocess

with the answers for my previous question, my estimateskeleton.py script now works perfectly  with the subprocess.Popen call. The while True function works as well, while the estimateskeleton.py script is running, I get all the output shown in the Console. Now I want to display the progress / Output of the script in Canvas to the users. In the code given below I cutted the Tkinter GUI stuff for clearity purposes. However, the scripts gives me the progress of the estimateskeleton.py in the Console but it doesn't update the Canvas, despite both commands are in the same while True loop.

So my question is: Do I need to thread the subprocess call in order to draw the output / progress of the estimateskeleton.py script on my canvas?

Best regards

**EDIT 1:** How would I thread this? Does the subprocess go in one Thread and the while true loop in another?

```
class canvasEditor():

    def __init__(self):
        self.cwidth=500
        self.cheight=300
        self.lastY=0
    #Funktionen für die Datei Menübar
    def clearCanvas(self,color="#FFFFFF"):
        #Formatierung des MappingCanvas
        canvas.configure(bg=color)
        canvas.delete("all")
    def clearCanvas2(self):
        canvasSkelett.delete("all")
    def calcSkeleton():
        myCE.clearCanvas("#000000")  

def calcSkeleton():
    myCE.addCanvasContent("processing")
    myFileChooser.setPathToSkelett()
    os.chdir("/media/sf_Th_Neuro/Scripts/vCGPDM/code/tracking/")
    os.putenv("PYTHONPATH",os.pathsep.join([os.getenv("PYTHONPATH",""),"/media/sf_MyFolder/Scripts/code/"]))

    p = sub.Popen(["python", "estimateskeleton.py","--d",myFileChooser.estimationFile],
                      stdout=sub.PIPE,
                      stderr=sub.STDOUT)
    lastY=1
    while True:
        line = p.stdout.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        if lastY > 0:
            canvas.create_text(1,lastY,fill="green",text=line,anchor=NW)
            lastY += 12
        else:
            canvas.create_text(1,1,fill="green",text=line,anchor=NW)
            lastY += 12
        print line
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: when you run `while` loop, then `mainloop` can't work and it can't update/redraw widgets with new content. You can use `after` instead of `while` or at least use `root.update()` inside `while` to let `mainloop` update/redraw widgets.

Comment: the root.update() fixed it for the moment! However I see the issue with while true in a mainloop, so I will look for a tkinter.after solution. Thanks a lot!